# How do I detect the id of a currently displayed element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gmail-api

I am basically using Gmail API to create send and reply to functionalities for myself. The problem is in the reply section. I am using jQuery to dynamically create `div`s for every message that appears in my inbox (*max-count:10*) and a separate set of `div`s (any single one to appear on clicking a mail link) wherein for each `div`, I am having the `modal-header` div for the subject, reply and close buttons whereas a `modal-body` div with an `iframe` for displaying the content.

[image: First set of divs]

[image: The "#message-modal-"+message.id window that pops up and becomes visible when I click on a link; this is what I want to fade out]

```js
var message1;

function appendMessageRow(message) {
  $('.table-inbox tbody').append(
    '<tr>\
            <td>' + getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From') + '</td>\
            <td>\
              <a href="#message-modal-' + message.id +
    '" data-toggle="modal" id="message-link-' + message.id + '">' +
    getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
    '</a>\
            </td>\
            <td>' + getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Date') + '</td>\
          </tr>'
  );

  $('body').append(
    '<div class="modal fade" id="message-modal-' + message.id +
    '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">\
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">\
              <div class="modal-content">\
    <div class="modal-header">\
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' +
    getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
    '</h4>\
     <button type="button"\
                          class="close"\
                          data-dismiss="modal"\
                          aria-label="Close" style="float:right;">\
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
     <span></span>\
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="#reply-modal" id="reply-button" class="btn btn-primary">Reply</a>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                  <iframe id="message-iframe-' + message.id + '" srcdoc="<p>Loading...</p>">\
                  </iframe>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
          </div>'
  );

  $('#message-link-' + message.id).on('click', function() {
    var ifrm = $('#message-iframe-' + message.id)[0].contentWindow.document;
    $('body', ifrm).html(getBody(message.payload));
    message1 = message;
  });

  $('#reply-button).on('
    click ',function(){
    $("#reply-to").val(getHeader(message1.payload.headers, 'From')); $("#reply-subject").val('RE: ' + getHeader(message1.payload.headers, 'Subject')); $("#message-modal-" + message1.id).fadeOut(); $('div.modal-backdrop.fade.in').fadeOut();
  });
}
```

I intend to use the **Reply** button to call a function which will fill the 'To' and 'Subject' field in the `reply-modal`(*Reply button is an **a** tag with href=#reply-modal*) that'd be visible after the `message-modal-message.id`div fades out. The problem is I am unable to get the id of this div which I need to fade out (along with that greyish background).

Also if you can see I need the whole `message` object and just not the `message.id` of the clicked message link so that I can transfer 'To' and 'Subject' to the newly appeared `reply-modal` div. But it just doesn't get the `message.id` of the clicked-on message but the last one in the list of mails displayed on the inbox page and so the `#message-modal-message.id` does not fade out as the `message.id` is not correct. Similarly, the 'To' and 'From' fields in the `reply-modal`div also contain information of the last mail in the list  - doesn't matter which mail you've opened. Also as the `message-modal-message.id` div does not disappear, the `reply-modal` div appears behind it and I have to close the it div to see the `reply-modal` div.
I even tried having a JS function on the outside instead of the jQuery selector method `$('#reply-modal').on('click',..` but couldn't do it.

Basically,
**How do I get the message object after a message has been opened to view?**

[image: The reply box that I would want the 'To' and 'Subject' headers from <code>message.payload</code> to show in]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what exactly I was talking about. Sorry I couldn't paste the whole code in the questions too if that created some sort of confusion while trying to understand the question.

'Reply' button **needs to be there for every message** we add as `div`s to the display page, which also uses the two critical variables `reply-to` and `reply-subject` to pass the required data to the new reply form that opens up.

The closing of the 'Show message' div which was not possible earlier, was also linked to the message-id, which now becomes accessible.

Everything else is pretty neat; the functions required to send the reply are the same as sending a new email and are present at the very end of the code.

What I was unable to do was capture the message id of the currently displayed message on the click of "Reply" button. This is a "better" solution than a workaround, but man would it be shorter if I could have done what I'd have had wanted!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gmail API demo</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <style>
    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      border: 0;
      min-height: 80%;
      height: 600px;
      display: flex;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Gmail API demo</h1>

    <button id="authorize-button" class="btn btn-primary hidden">Authorize</button>

    <a href="#compose-modal" data-toggle="modal" id="compose-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right hidden">Compose</a>


    <table class="table table-striped table-inbox hidden">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>From</th>
          <th>Subject</th>
          <th>Date/Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="compose-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Compose</h4>
        </div>
        <form onsubmit="return sendEmail();">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="compose-to" placeholder="To" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-message" placeholder="Message" rows="10" required></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" id="send-button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="reply-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Reply</h4>
        </div>
        <form onsubmit="return sendReply();">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="reply-to" required disabled/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reply-subject" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="reply-message" placeholder="Message" rows="10" required></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" id="reply-message-id" />
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" id="reply-button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="withinViewport.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.withinviewport.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

    function handleClientLoad() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
      window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    }

    function checkAuth() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scopes,
        immediate: true
      }, handleAuthResult);
    }

    function handleAuthClick() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scopes,
        immediate: false
      }, handleAuthResult);
      return false;
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        loadGmailApi();
        $('#compose-button').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#authorize-button').remove();
        $('.table-inbox').removeClass("hidden");
      } else {
        $('#authorize-button').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#authorize-button').on('click', function() {
          handleAuthClick();
        });
      }
    }

    function loadGmailApi() {
      gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', displayInbox);
    }

    function displayInbox() {
      var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
        'userId': 'me',
        'labelIds': 'INBOX',
        'maxResults': 10
      });
      request.execute(function(response) {
        $.each(response.messages, function() {
          var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
            'userId': 'me',
            'id': this.id
          });
          messageRequest.execute(appendMessageRow);
        });
      });
    }

    function appendMessageRow(message) {
      var reply_to = (getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Reply-to') !== '' ? getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Reply-to') : getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From')).replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');
      var reply_subject = 'Re: ' + getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject').replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');
      $('.table-inbox tbody').append(
        '<tr>\
            <td>' + getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From') + '</td>\
            <td>\
              <a href="#message-modal-' + message.id +
        '" data-toggle="modal" id="message-link-' + message.id + '">' +
        getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
        '</a>\
            </td>\
            <td>' + getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Date') + '</td>\
          </tr>'
      );

      $('body').append(
        '<div class="modal fade" id="message-modal-' + message.id +
        '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">\
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">\
              <div class="modal-content">\
    <div class="modal-header">\
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' +
        getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
        '</h4>\
     <button type="button"\
                          class="close"\
                          data-dismiss="modal"\
                          aria-label="Close" style="float:right;">\
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
     <span></span>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                  <iframe id="message-iframe-' + message.id + '" srcdoc="<p>Loading...</p>">\
                  </iframe>\
      <div class="modal-footer">\
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary reply-button" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reply-modal"\
   onclick="fillInReply(\'' + reply_to + '\',\'' + reply_subject + '\',\'' + getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Message-ID') + '\');">Reply</button>\
   </div> \
                </div>\
            </div>\
   </div>\
          </div>'
      );


      $('#message-link-' + message.id).on('click', function() {
        var ifrm = $('#message-iframe-' + message.id)[0].contentWindow.document;
        $('body', ifrm).html(getBody(message.payload));
      });
    }



    function getHeader(headers, index) {
      var header = '';
      $.each(headers, function() {
        if (this.name === index) {
          header = this.value;
        }
      });
      return header;
    }

    function getBody(message) {
      var encodedBody = '';
      if (typeof message.parts === 'undefined') {
        encodedBody = message.body.data;
      } else {
        encodedBody = getHTMLPart(message.parts);
      }
      encodedBody = encodedBody.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\s/g, '');
      return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(encodedBody)));
    }

    function getHTMLPart(arr) {
      for (var x = 0; x <= arr.length; x++) {
        if (typeof arr[x].parts === 'undefined') {
          if (arr[x].mimeType === 'text/html') {
            return arr[x].body.data;
          }
        } else {
          return getHTMLPart(arr[x].parts);
        }
      }
      return '';
    }

    function sendEmail() {
      $('#send-button').addClass('disabled');

      sendMessage({
          'To': $('#compose-to').val(),
          'Subject': $('#compose-subject').val()
        },
        $('#compose-message').val(),
        composeTidy
      );
      return false;
    }

    function sendMessage(headers_obj, message, callback) {
      var email = '';

      for (var header in headers_obj)
        email += header += ": " + headers_obj[header] + "\r\n";

      email += "\r\n" + message;

      var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
        'userId': 'me',
        'resource': {
          'raw': window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
        }
      });

      return sendRequest.execute(callback);
    }

    function fillInReply(to, subject, message_id) {
      $('#reply-to').val(to);
      $('#reply-subject').val(subject);
      $('#reply-message-id').val(message_id);
    }

    function sendReply() {
      $('#reply-button').addClass('disabled');
      sendMessage({
          'To': $('#reply-to').val(),
          'Subject': $('#reply-subject').val(),
          'In-Reply-To': $('#reply-message-id').val()
        },
        $('#reply-message').val(),
        replyTidy
      );
      return false;
    }



    function replyTidy() {
      $('#reply-modal').modal('hide');
      $('#reply-message').val('');
      $('#reply-button').removeClass('disabled');
    }


    function composeTidy() {
      $('#compose-modal').modal('hide');

      $('#compose-to').val('');
      $('#compose-subject').val('');
      $('#compose-message').val('');

      $('#send-button').removeClass('disabled');
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
</body>

</html>
```